# Is there an easier/shorter code for switch case in this case?

Tags: java, switch-statement, case

I have to sort a list of objects by the date provided in them. My initial thought was to use a switch case. But that means a maximum of 31 cases.
Here is the code im using:

```
if (e.getSource() == btnSalesPerDay)
        {
            //int i =0;
            SalesTextArea.setText("");

            Object[] possibilities = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31"};
            String dayOption = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame,"Pick a day you wish to display the records for : ", "Catagory pick", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, possibilities,"ham");

            switch(dayOption)
            {
            case 1:
                if(salesdata[i].day == 1)
                {
                    int i =0;
                    while (salesdata != null)
                    {
                        SalesTextArea.insert("\t" + salesdata[i].totalPrice, 0);
                        SalesTextArea.insert("\t" + salesdata[i].year, 0);
                        SalesTextArea.insert("\t" + salesdata[i].month, 0);
                        SalesTextArea.insert("\t" + salesdata[i].day, 0);
                        SalesTextArea.insert("\t" + salesdata[i].customerName, 0);
                        SalesTextArea.insert("\t" + salesdata[i].salesNo, 0);
                        SalesTextArea.insert("\n", 0);
                        i++;
                    }
                }
                break;
case 2:
                if(salesdata[i].day == 2)
                {
                    int i =0;
                    while (salesdata != null)
                    {
                        SalesTextArea.insert("\t" + salesdata[i].totalPrice, 0);
                        SalesTextArea.insert("\t" + salesdata[i].year, 0);
                        SalesTextArea.insert("\t" + salesdata[i].month, 0);
                        SalesTextArea.insert("\t" + salesdata[i].day, 0);
                        SalesTextArea.insert("\t" + salesdata[i].customerName, 0);
                        SalesTextArea.insert("\t" + salesdata[i].salesNo, 0);
                        SalesTextArea.insert("\n", 0);
                        i++;
                    }
                }
                break;
```

It goes on up to the 31 cases..
My question is.. is there a simpler way? Whats the most efficient way to go about this?

Thanks :)

Comment: Please show at least two cases, so we can see what, if anything, cases have in common.

Comment: Yep, how do the cases differ??

Comment: `while (salesdata != null)` seems like an infinite loop. How does `salesdata` ever become `null`?

Comment: And why aren't you just using a variable?

Comment: May be just a for with only particular cases like 29 30 and 31 could work and what abut that infinite loop it makes no sense..

Comment: Cases are all the same, thats why i didnt show the other cases.. i'll post the edit.

Comment: Is it possible to factor out all the `SalesTextArea.insert()` calls into another method?

Comment: What are you trying to DO?  If you are doing the same thing, no matter what day it was picked, then what is the point?

Also, if you're using a switch on a string, make sure the case statements are quoted, e.g. `case "1":`.

Comment: I have a hunch you can probably just do salesdata[i-1] where i is the input, but we need another couple test cases

Comment: there are no differences between the two cases....

Comment: The code makes no sense.. You don't use salesdata[i].day in any case so why, just why ? Just do it once without switch case in a loop

Comment: @YTowOnt9 Ive tried using that code in console. It worked perfectly fine. Salesdata is extracted from a file. It did give a nullpointerexception, But it was handled.

Comment: @YTowOnt9 oh! Thanks for pointing that out!! :) didnt realize it.

Comment: @ShifaTsar No problem. You might be better just using a for loop up to the length of `salesdata` and not testing for `null` at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need a single loop:

```
String dayOption = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame,"Pick a day you wish to display the records for : ", "Catagory pick", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, possibilities,"ham");

int chosenDay = Integer.parseInt(dayOption);
for (SalesData item : array) {
    if (item.day == chosenDay) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably need to break

Comment: For what it's worth, you [Shifa] should probably should change the default option from "ham" (from the JOptionPane tutorial) to something that makes sense here (likely "1").

Comment: @MiguelDickson Ham part was from the java documentations.. i forgot to change it. Thanks for pointing out :)